# What kind of machine learning model could I use on this dataset?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, dataset, model, exploratory-data-analysis

I am a beginner to data science. I found this dataset that covers natural disaster incidents in Afghanistan from 2016 - present. Here are the 13 columns: REGION (South West, North, etc), PROV_CODE (Province code), PROV_NAME, DIST_CODE (district code), DIST_NAME, INC_DATE (Incident date), INC_TYPE (Incidence type), Persons_killed, Persons_injured, Individuals_affected, Families_affected, Houses_damaged, Houses_destroyed. After performing exploratory data analysis, here are some of my results (I am limited to what I can upload so if you want to see the whole script let me know):[image]

My next step is to utilize any ML algorithm (regression, classification, clustering), but I am stuck. I went about my project in the wrong way, rather than first coming up with a scientific question, and then seeking out the dataset, I sought out the dataset first and am now trying to figure out the scientific question.

Would it be silly to do a regression model that predicts the number of persons killed given the other input features? It seems obvious it would be correlated to number of persons injured, so would it be kind of cheating and not useful? Another idea is predicting the incident type based on other features using classification. Every question I come up seems silly. It is a beginner project for Intro to Data Science so I may be overthinking it.

I think the best model could be using clustering to identify spatial clusters of incidents (unfortunately I don't have geographic coordinates of each disaster, but I do have the district that it occurred in, so I don't know if this is possible).

What are your thoughts? Do you have a specific scientific question that you could try answering using a simple ML model on this dataset?

Comment: Clustering techniques such as K-means can be used to detect patterns or groupings in data without preexisting labels. For example, you may discover clusters of districts with similar types of incidents or damage levels. I can't think of a good regression or classification idea with this data.